# Meteor user profile not being published

Tags: meteor

According to meteor docs, user profile information is always published:

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user

However, `Meteor.user.profile` is `undefined` in my Chrome console but when I check in the mongodb server side cli it contains the proper user data.

Here's my template code:

```
<head>
  <title>test-login</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> userInfo}}
</body>
<template name="userInfo">
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> userLoggedIn}}
  {{else}}
    {{> userLoggedOut}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="userLoggedIn">
  {{#if loggingIn}}
    <a>Logging In</a>
  {{else}}
    <a>{{curentUser.profile.name}}</a>
  {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="userLoggedOut">
  <a id="login">Login with Github</a>
</template>
```

My client side js:

```
Template.userLoggedOut.events({
  "click #login": function (e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.loginWithGithub({
      requestPermissions: ['user', 'public_repo']
    });
  }
});

Template.userLoggedIn.events({
  "click #logout": function (e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
});
```

My server side js:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: 'github'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: 'github',
  clientId: 'xxxxxx',
  secret: 'yyyyyyyyyyy'
});
```

I'm using the latest meteor `0.8.0` with only the following packages:

```
standard-app-packages
autopublish
insecure
accounts-github
service-configuration
```

Comment: Besides @sbking's explanation, the other problem I had was that currentUser was misspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Meteor.user().profile`, not `Meteor.user.profile`.